# Input Username and Password = ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, string, input, int

I am new to Python and I would like help with this issue.
I want to create a code where I input the username and password but I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Also, I can input the name but can't input the age

Here is my code:

```
name = (input("Tell me your name"))
age = int(input())
```

Comment: Looks like you pressed Enter without entering any value for `age`. It's telling you that it can't convert an empty string to a number, which you would get if you did as I described.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the code stopping when an wrong value is sent is using `try: ... except:...`

```
name = (input("Tell me your name"))
Try:
  age = int(input('Your Age:'))
Except:
  print 'wrong input for age'
  age = int(input('Your Age: '))
```

this will print a message in case you place a wrong input and then start the input over again... but it works one time, if you put a wrong input again the error will continue

Comment: Why design it so that it only gives you one chance of being incorrect? It's also not valid syntax, and having a blanket `except` is bad practice